# Java 8 streams - each step in the chain evaluated for entire input or do items get passed through?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Say if I have this trivial program

```
    List<String> input = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
    List<String> result = input.stream()
            .map(x -> x + " " + x)
            .filter(y -> !y.startsWith("1"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Behind the scenes does it work like a) or b)

A

```
map
  "1" + " " + "1"
  "2" + " " + "2"
  "3" + " " + "3"
filter
  "1 1" does not begin with "1"? = false
  "2 2" does not begin with "1"? = true
  "3 3" does not begin with "1"? = true
collect
  add "2 2" to list
  add "3 3" to list
result = List("2 2", "3 3")
```

B

```
map
  "1" + " " + "1"
filter
  "1 1" does not begin with "1"? = false
map
  "2" + " " + "2"
filter
  "2 2" does not begin with "1"? = true
collect
  add "2 2" to list
map
  "3" + " " + "3"
filter
  "3 3" does not begin with "1"? = true
collect
  add "3 3" to list
result = List("2 2", "3 3")
```

Comment: Wild guess: one at a time; but you can easily check that by printing statements in your lambdas

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works like option B, not necessarilly in that exact order, but more on that it does every operation on one element at a time.

The reasoning behind this is that variables only pass the stream **once**, so you need to perform all actions when you have that element right now, because once the element has passed, it is gone forever (from the stream's point of view).

Your code is, in a linear setting, very very very roughly equivalent to the following code, this is a very simplified version, but I hope you get the idea:

```
Collection<String> input = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
Function<String, String> mapper = x -> x + " " + x;
Predicate<String> filter = y -> !y.startsWith("1");
Collector<String, ?, List<String>> toList = Collectors.toList();

List<String> list = ((Supplier<List<String>>)toList.supplier()).get();
for (String in : input) {
    in = mapper.apply(in);
    if (filter.test(in)) {
        ((BiConsumer<List<String>, String>)toList.accumulator()).accept(list, in);
    }
}
```

What you see here, is:

- As input a `Collection<String>`, *your* input.
- A `Function<String, String>` matching your `map()`.
- A `Predciate<String>` matching your `filter()`.
- A `Collector<String, ?, List<String>>` matching your `collect()`, this is a collector that operates on elements of type `String`, uses intermediate storage `?` and gives a `List<String>`.

What it then does is:

- Obtain a new list, from the supplier (type: `Supplier<List<String>>`) of the collector.
- Loop over every element of the input, done internally when operating on a `Stream<String>`, I am using a `Collection<String>` here for expliciteness such that we still have a connection to the old Java 7 world.
- Apply your mapping function.
- Test your filter predicate.
- Obtain the accumulator (type: `BiConsumer<List<String>, String>`) of the `toList` collector, this is the binary consumer that takes as arguments the `List<String>` it already has, and the `String` it wants to add.
- Feed our `list` and `in` to the accumulator.

Please take a very careful note that the real implementations is much much more advanced, as operations can happen in any order and multiple ones can happen, and much more.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the real implementation is much more advanced, but your explanation is generally what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there any possible way to get the predicates means what user defined startsWith or Contains or whatever conditions that has been defined.

Comment: Note that 'method B' behaviour is what allows stream operations like `findFirst()` and `findAny()` and other 'short-circuit terminal operations' to be fast.

Comment: Note that with stateful intermediate operations like `sorted()` behaviour differ.

Answer (score 5):

One of the benefit of streams is [lazy-evaluation of intermediate operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html). That means, when the terminal operation, `collect()` in this case is executed, it asks for an element from previous intermediate operation - `filter()`, which in turns gets the element from `map()`, which in turns operates on first element from `list.stream()`. Same flow is followed for all the elements. So yes, the execution is more like option B.

Also, since the collector returned by `Collectors.toList()` is ordered, the elements are guaranteed to execute in order. In some cases, the evaluation might go out of order, when [`UNORDERED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html#UNORDERED) chararacteristic is set for a collector.

Comment: Thanks, succinctly put!